# MySQL: Converting Row to Columns Based on Field Values

Tags: mysql, database, sql, mysql-workbench

I am using MySQL Workbench 8.0.

I will break my question into two parts as I believe the first part will be straightforward (but is slightly beyond my current SQL knowledge level) but the second part may not be so straightforward.

### QUESTION PART 1

I have the following source data:

| PKey | attr1 | attr2 | data1 | data2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | C | 1 | 14 |
| 1 | A | C | 2 | 16 |
| 2 | A | C | 3 | 44 |
| 3 | A | D | 1 | 91 |
| 4 | A | D | 2 | 9 |
| 5 | A | D | 3 | 71 |
| 6 | B | C | 1 | 31 |
| 7 | B | C | 2 | 3 |
| 8 | B | C | 3 | 38 |
| 9 | B | D | 1 | 1 |
| 10 | B | D | 2 | 111 |
| 11 | B | D | 3 | 30 |

`attr1` and `attr2` each take on two possible values. `attr1` can take on values of **A** and **B**. `attr2` can take on values of **C** and **D**. So, these two fields taken together as a pair have four possible values: **AC**, **AD**, **BC**, **BD**.

`data1` can take on N different values, though only three are shown above to keep the example simple. Any solution offered to my questions below should not assume that `data1` is limited to values in the range 1 - 3.

As a first step, I would like to write a query that transforms rows to columns, based on the (`attr1`, `attr2`) pairs **AC**, **AD**, **BC**, **BD**, as follows:

| data1 | AC | AD | BC | BD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 14 | 91 | 31 | 1 |
| 2 | 16 | 9 | 3 | 111 |
| 3 | 44 | 71 | 38 | 30 |

Implicit in this problem statement is that the tuple values (`attr1`, `attr2`, `data1`) are unique.

**How may I write a SQL query that will accomplish this?**

### QUESTION PART 2

The more challenging part of the problem I'm facing is that the tuple values (`attr1`, `attr2`, `data1`) are not actually unique as was assumed in part 1 above.

Here is a more accurate representation of my data:

| PKey | attr1 | attr2 | data1 | data2 | RecCreated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | C | 1 | 14 | 2024-01-01 13:00:00 |
| 1 | A | C | 2 | 16 | 2024-01-01 13:00:00 |
| 2 | A | C | 3 | 44 | 2024-01-01 13:00:00 |
| 3 | A | D | 1 | 91 | 2024-01-01 13:00:01 |
| 4 | A | D | 2 | 9 | 2024-01-01 13:00:02 |
| 5 | A | D | 3 | 71 | 2024-01-01 13:00:02 |
| 6 | B | C | 1 | 31 | 2024-01-01 13:00:02 |
| 7 | B | C | 2 | 3 | 2024-01-01 13:00:02 |
| 8 | B | C | 3 | 38 | 2024-01-01 13:00:02 |
| 9 | B | D | 1 | 1 | 2024-01-01 13:00:03 |
| 10 | B | D | 2 | 111 | 2024-01-01 13:00:03 |
| 11 | B | D | 3 | 30 | 2024-01-01 13:00:03 |
| 12 | A | C | 1 | 66 | 2024-03-21 09:57:20 |
| 13 | A | C | 2 | 23 | 2024-03-21 09:57:20 |
| 14 | A | C | 3 | 54 | 2024-03-21 09:57:21 |
| 15 | A | D | 1 | 19 | 2024-03-21 09:57:21 |
| 16 | A | D | 2 | 18 | 2024-03-21 09:57:21 |
| 17 | A | D | 3 | 33 | 2024-03-21 09:57:22 |
| 18 | B | C | 1 | 87 | 2024-03-21 09:57:22 |
| 19 | B | C | 2 | 19 | 2024-03-21 09:57:22 |
| 20 | B | C | 3 | 9 | 2024-03-21 09:57:22 |
| 21 | B | D | 1 | 10 | 2024-03-21 09:57:23 |
| 22 | B | D | 2 | 83 | 2024-03-21 09:57:23 |
| 23 | B | D | 3 | 13 | 2024-03-21 09:57:23 |

As can now be seen, the (`attr1`, `attr2`, `data1`) tuples can appear more than once. In the case above, each possible tuple appears twice (though there is not a fixed limit on how many times such a tuple can appear).

I would like the query I'm trying to develop to return the following:

| data1 | AC | AD | BC | BD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 14 | 91 | 31 | 1 |
| 2 | 16 | 9 | 3 | 111 |
| 3 | 44 | 71 | 38 | 30 |
| 1 | 66 | 19 | 87 | 10 |
| 2 | 23 | 18 | 19 | 83 |
| 3 | 54 | 33 | 9 | 13 |

The problem is knowing which values of `AC`, `AD`, `BC`, and `BD` should be grouped together with a given value of `data1`. For example, instead of the desired groupings shown above, the following (incorrect) groupings for `data1` = 1 could have been selected:

| data1 | AC | AD | BC | BD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 14 | 19 | 31 | 10 |
| 1 | 66 | 91 | 87 | 1 |

The only thing I have to correctly form the grouping on is the `RecCreated` field. Values that are "close together" in time should be grouped together. Of course, this requires defining "close together". For the purposes of this post, let's define a group as the set of values which are within **3 minutes** of each other based on the `RecCreated` field.

**How may I write a SQL query that will accomplish this?**